# cannot puts the variable I just assigned on the same line

Tags: ruby

I cannot puts the variable on the same line but could on different lines
my input

```
  word = 'e2ed2d' puts word
```

my output

```
bundle exec ruby main.rb
    main.rb:21: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input
    word = 'e2ed2d' puts word
                    ^~~~
    exit status 1
```

Comment: Use `puts word = 'e2ed2d'` – the assignment is evaluated first and returns the assigned value which is then being printed.

Comment: Note: You only need `bundle exec` if you're using gems, and even then, it may not be necessary. For trivial programs, `ruby main.rb` is sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby, parentheses are optional in argument lists for message sends, as is the receiver (implicitly defaulting to `self`). Therefore,

```ruby
foo bar baz
```

is equivalent to

```ruby
foo(bar(baz))
```

which is equivalent to

```ruby
self.foo(self.bar(self.baz))

# or, depending on whether `baz` is a local variable or a message

self.foo(self.bar(baz))
```

More generally, whenever you see two tokens next to each other, the only valid interpretation is that the first token is a message and the second token is an argument. (The only exception being operator messages, e.g. `a + b`.)

However, there is no meaningful way of interpreting your code as a message send:

```ruby
word = 'e2ed2d' puts word
```

What would that be equivalent to?

```ruby
word = self.'e2ed2d'(self.puts(word))
```

or

```ruby
word = 'e2ed2d'(puts(word))
```

That makes no sense: `String` literals don't take any arguments (only message sends and block invocations do), and a `String` literal is also not a valid message identifier.

What you actually want are two separate expressions, so you need to separate those two separate expressions with an *expression separator*. Ruby has two general expression separators: you can either use a semicolon `;` or a newline, so either

```ruby
word = 'e2ed2d'
puts word
```

or

```ruby
word = 'e2ed2d'; puts word
```

would be okay.

In some specific contexts, there are also context-specific additional expression separators. For example, in a *conditional expression*, you can separate the condition from the consequence using the keyword `then` as an additional context-specific separator:

```ruby
if 2 < 3 then '2 is less than 3' else '2 is greater than or equal to 3' end

if 2 < 3; '2 is less than 3' else '2 is greater than or equal to 3' end

if 2 < 3
'2 is less than 3' else '2 is greater than or equal to 3' end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `;`:

```
word = 'e2ed2d'; puts word
```